# python regular expression could not find all images files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to grap all the image files in web pages by using re.compile

```
title=re.compile("<img src='(.*)jpg'")
```

but it cannot catch all the scentence that end with " jpg' ", it only got 3 very long strings in a web with many images (many links end with jpg) , can someone help me with that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is too greedy. Reign it in:

```
re.compile("<img src='([^']*)jpg'")
```

However, the better approach is to use a proper HTML parser, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
for image in soup.find_all('img', src=True):
    print image['src']
```

finds all `<img />` tags with a `src` attribute, for example.

Comment: +1 for solving the problem as well as giving a better way to do it. @hln, you should look up the different ways to do lazy matching -- Martijn uses the fact that there will be an ending quote, you could also have a slightly more complicated regex with `*?`.